# ZSH: how to make navigation in command line more bash-like?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I recently installed `zsh` and really like it but I just don't know how to navigate the command line. `Home` and `End` keys do not work and `Ctrl-Left` `Ctrl-Right` neither.

I set it to `vi mode` since I am rather familiar with `vi`, but for me it's a fallback if nothing else is available. I prefer using `nano`. And I don't have any idea how to apply vi codes to a command line ?!?

Comment: mh, i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638012, but I still need solutions for Ctrl Left and right, insert

Answer (score 0):

found the solution myself. happy now ;)

put this into `~/.zshrc`

```
# Pos1 (home) & Ende (End) keys
bindkey '^[[H' beginning-of-line
bindkey '^[[F' end-of-line

# delete key:
bindkey  "^[[3~"  delete-char

# cntrl + left / right
bindkey ";5D" backward-word
bindkey ";5C" forward-word
```

Comment: `.inputrc` - content?

Comment: no, `.zshrc`. `.input.rc` is non existant.